# Removing unused command line tools when compiling mariadb/mysql from source

Tags: mysql, compilation, cmake, mariadb, embedded-linux

*(Note, although I'm using mariadb, I'm including the mysql tag as well, since they are similar)*

I'm compiling mariadb from source (via Buildroot for an embedded Linux system) and I'm trying to minimise the image size. I noticed that there are a fair few command line tools installed that I don't use. These include:

- mysql_client_test
- mysqltest
- mysqldump
- mysqlslap
- ...etc

I don't intend to use these tools in my application and would like the CMake system to not build and install them. However, I'm struggling to find any options that would allow me to do that. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question because I don't see suitable CMake options either. But here is some other options which could help you a bit:

```
-DWITH_UNIT_TESTS=0
-DWITHOUT_ROCKSDB_STORAGE_ENGINE=1
-DWITHOUT_MROONGA_STORAGE_ENGINE=1
-DWITHOUT_CONNECT_STORAGE_ENGINE=1
-DWITHOUT_SPHINX_STORAGE_ENGINE=1
-DWITHOUT_TOKUDB_STORAGE_ENGINE=1
-DWITHOUT_SPIDER_STORAGE_ENGINE=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This would not be trivial I don't think, or IMO particularly useful.  The tools are there because most users are likely to use them at some point.  I recommend you leave them be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I should have mentioned in my question, but this is for an embedded system, which won't have any human users as such. I'm trying to cut down the image size. I may have to manually delete the unused files using Buildroot scripts.

Comment: Ah that makes so much more sense!  Thanks for the comment, sorry I didn't have a good suggestion